# How to make a custom relational operator in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, operators

I am working with Doubles that have a range of `0..<360`. I want to create a switch statement that will have 8 cases. A case for 0, 90, 180 and 270, and a case for the values in between. It seems that the half-open operator will not satisfy what I'm trying to do here. I'm thinking the solution may be to create a custom relational operator. Let's call it `<..<`

```
case 0:
case 0<..<90:
case 90:
case 90<..<180:
case 180:
case 180<..<270:
case 270:
case 270<..<360:
```

I've looked into creating a custom infix operator that returns a `Bool`but that won't work because the arguments would only include the lhs and rhs.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: The cases do not have to be mutually exclusive, they are checked in the defined order and the first one wins. You can have a `case: 0` followed by `case: 0..<90`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. That works great.

Comment: I'm very curious to see if you ever get "spot on" numbers in real life. I suspect you'll get the ranges firing most/all of the time?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Those numbers are definitely edge cases. The value I'm switching on is a `CLHeading` coming from a `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method, which result in some very "precise" Double values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your switch is unnecessarily complicated. See if this works for you:

```
let value: Double = 180

switch value {
    case 0:
        print("exactly 0")
    case 0..<90:
        print("less than 90")
    case 90:
        print("exactly 90")
    case 90..<180:
        print("less than 180")
    case 180:
        print("exactly 180")
    case 180..<270:
        print("less than 270")
    case 270:
        print("exactly 270")
    default:
        print("less than 360")
}
```

Comment: In this circumstance I would need to perform a different action if the value was 180 than if it was 180.1. Thus the half-open relational operator doesn't meet my requirement.

Comment: Swift's `case` don't fall through. It exits the `switch` statement as soon as a match is found. See my updated answer